# CSV.generate and converters?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to create a converter to remove newline characters from CSV output.

I've got:

```
nonewline=lambda do |s|
  s.gsub(/(\r?\n)+/,' ')
end
```

I've verified that this works properly IF I load a variable and then run something like:

```
csv=CSV(variable,:converters=>[nonewline])
```

However, I'm attempting to use this code to update a bunch of preexisting code using `CSV.generate`, and it does not appear to work at all.

```
CSV.generate(:converters=>[nonewline]) do |csv|
  csv << ["hello\ngoodbye"]
end
```

returns:

```
"\"hello\ngoodbye\"\n"
```

I've tried quite a few things as well as trying other examples I've found online, and it appears as though `:converters` has no effect when used with `CSV.generate`.

Is this correct, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your converter as as below :

```
CSV::Converters[:nonewline] = lambda do |s|
  s.gsub(/(\r?\n)+/,' ')
end
```

Then do :

```
CSV.generate(:converters => [:nonewline]) do |csv|
  csv << ["hello\ngoodbye"]
end
```

Read the documentation [`Converters`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#Converters) .

Okay, above part I didn't remove, as to show you how to write the custom `CSV` converters. The way you wrote it is incorrect.

Read the documentation of [`CSV::generate`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate)

> This method wraps a String you provide, or an empty default String, in a CSV object which is passed to the provided block. You can use the block to append CSV rows to the String and when the block exits, the final String will be returned.

After reading the docs, it is quite clear that this method is for writing to a csv file, not for reading. Now all the converters options ( like `:converters`, `:header_converters`) is applied, when you are reading a **CSV** file, but not applied when you are writing into a **CSV** file.

Let me show you 2 examples to illustrate this more clearly.

```
require 'csv'

string = <<_
foo,bar
baz,quack
_

File.write('a',string)

CSV::Converters[:upcase] = lambda do |s|
  s.upcase
end
```

I am reading from a **CSV** file, so `:converters` option is applied to it.

```
CSV.open('a','r',:converters => :upcase) do |csv|
  puts csv.read
end
```

**output**

```
# >> FOO
# >> BAR
# >> BAZ
# >> QUACK
```

Now I am writing into the **CSV** file, converters option is not applied.

```
CSV.open('a','w',:converters => :upcase) do |csv|
  csv << ['dog','cat']
end

CSV.read('a') # => [["dog", "cat"]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work.  I get the same output as I did above '"\"hello\ngoodbye\"\n"'

Comment: @JimMacKenzie As per the doc it should work,, I am checking why that converter is not running...

Comment: @JimMacKenzie It seems to me a bug.. If you tell me, your requirement, I can tell you other workarounds if any.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I was thinking, but it wasn't readily apparent to me that it was only for reading.

Comment: If you do have an idea of how to "globally" change fields like I wanted originally, I'd greatly appreciate hearing about it.  Basically, we've got data which may contain new lines and I need a way to output it to CSV, without modifying the code too much.  We found a specific field which was giving us problems and I added a line to the code to fix that specific field, but I would like to find a method where I wouldn't have to do major updates to all our CSV outputs to make sure this was fixed everywhere.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie If you are reading the file, then *converters* will do. But yes, converter will run on each filed, not only to any specific field.

Comment: That's the problem...we're not reading a CSV, just creating one, via CSV.generate, from data coming from different places.  I was hoping there would be some easy way to modify on write, not just read, as `:converters` does.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie From where data is coming? I means source ? You need to handle it, before writing to a csv, externally.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to remove newlines using `:converters` did not work.

I had to override the << method from `csv.rb` adding the following code to it:

```
# Change all CR/NL's into one space
row.map! { |element|
  if element.is_a?(String)
    element.gsub(/(\r?\n)+/,' ')
  else
    element
  end
}
```

Placed right before

`output = row.map(&@quote).join(@col_sep) + @row_sep  # quote and separate`

at line 21.

I would think this would be a good patch to CSV, as newlines will always produce bad CSV output.